# How to remove numeric keys when converting a json object to xml in java

Tags: java, json, xml

I am new to JSON and XML and I got a weird issue which am trying to work on since few days now. No luck yet.

There is a json object which is being sent to my program as String. Now I need to convert the given string to json and then to XML. My output should be a String of my converted XML.

I was able to convert the string to JSON and then to XML without any issues. Sample code below

```
org.json.JSONObject jsonFileObject = new org.json.JSONObject(json);
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-15\"?>\n<"+root+">" 
                 + org.json.XML.toString(jsonFileObject) + "</"+root+">";
```

But the problem is there are few keys in the json object which are numeric and we need to remove such keys.

Sample JSON

```
{
"product": {
    "p1": true,
     "test": {
        "1000": [
        {
        "name": "name1",
        "id": "id1"
        }
                ],
        "2100": [
        {
        "name": "name2",
        "id": "id2"
        }
        ],
        "3200": [
        {
        "name": "name3",
        "id": "id3"
        }
        ],
        "8340": [
        {
        "name": "name4",
        "id": "id4"
        }
        ],
        "6200": [
        {
        "name": "name5",
        "id": "id5"
        }
        ]
    },
    "p2": "p2 test"
  }
}
```

In the above case my output should be

```
<test/>
```

Here the name and id are not always available. sometimes they might be empty as well.

Can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, looks like your JSON doesn't parse very well. I would sugest to use PARSE command first

```
var json = '{"test": [{"1000": [{"name": "name1", "id": "id1" }  ], "2100": [ { "name": "name2", "id": "id2" }] }]}';

var jsonFileObject = JSON.parse(json);
```

If you can parse it, then as an object is ease to manipulate it. For instance, you can loop over all elements and remove, alter, or anything and then convert it to XML.Look at this reference: [Filtering json object by key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444958/filtering-json-object-by-key-value)

Answer (score 0):

This JSON can be converted to this XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<product>
  <p1 boolean="true">true</p1>
  <test>
    <__GE__000 array="true">
      <name>name1</name>
      <id>id1</id>
    </__GE__000>
    <__GI__100 array="true">
      <name>name2</name>
      <id>id2</id>
    </__GI__100>
    <__GM__200 array="true">
      <name>name3</name>
      <id>id3</id>
    </__GM__200>
    <__HA__340 array="true">
      <name>name4</name>
      <id>id4</id>
    </__HA__340>
    <__GY__200 array="true">
      <name>name5</name>
      <id>id5</id>
    </__GY__200>
   </test>
  <p2>p2 test</p2>
</product>
```